# How did the jet airplane knock one of them out?

Tags: chronicle

In Chronicle, the three guys learn how to fly.  While playing around they end up encountering a jet airplane.  In this encounter one of them gets knocked out.  I didn’t see him get hit by it, so how did he get knocked out?

Comment: I always imagined it as he passed out from fear of almost being hit by a plane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *possibly* a plot hole.

To be knocked out, he would have to have been hit by the plane.

But a commercial airliner flying at that height (around 1000 feet) would be doing at least 150 knots (290 km/h or 170 mi/h) which would *obliterate* anything.

But by this time we've seen that the boys are able to protect themselves with their "powers". It may have been that their powers weren't quite strong enough to protect them from the full impact with the plane resulting in one being knocked out.

Comment: It was also explained, I believe, that they have to see the damage incoming in order to protect themself

Answer (score 3):

It was cut out the scene, but I just watched this, and I remember hearing the hit.  It was implied that the guy was hit. It was sort of a messy scene, but I re-iterate that I am pretty sure that the sound of the hit was there.